# Why are two-port networks able to use a dependent source but not an independent source?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current

A two-port network can be modeled as black box with two-port parameters provided the two-port network consists of no internal independent sources.

This restriction does not apply to a two-port network with dependent sources, why the difference as both are sources?

Comment: define those terms ... dependent and independent

Comment: What if the source is a single server running zero to five virtual machines? What if there are multiple servers on the same card?

Comment: It probably depends on the context, but what you say is basically wrong. Any N-port linear network can indeed be modelled as per Thevenin, Norton or a mix of the two, no matter the dependant or not generators inside. This is very common when modelling bias or noise voltage or currents in opamps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This restriction does not apply to a two-port network with dependent sources, why the difference as both are sources?

When you define a two-port, you're saying the network will obey a rule of the form

$${\rm outputs} = \left[ {\rm matrix} \right] {\rm inputs}$$

Where the inputs are one set or linear combination of the port voltages or currents, and the outputs are the remaining voltages or currents, and the matrix contains whichever network parameters we chose (Z-parameters, H-parameters, S-parameters, ...)

This means if the inputs are 0, then the outputs will be 0. If there is an independent source in the network, then this wouldn't be true and our matrix description of the network wouldn't be valid.

However if there is a dependent source in the network, then its output will be proportional to some linear combination of the input signals, so it can be readily handled with the network matrix description.